Why does the training fully-connected neural network (FNN) change after interrupting?
I am training the plane fully-connected neural nets and I noticed that after interrupting it the character of training changes. I interrupt it to check the results. And then I continue the process, but sometimes it reaches a plateau immediately after interrupting.
Why it has place and is it a good way to interrupt training to check the results and then continue the process?
I use the next code for training:
iters = 10000
optimizer=torch.optim.LBFGS(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
def train():
    for step in iters:
        def closure():
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss  = model(input)
            loss.backward()
            return loss
        optimizer.step(closure)
        if step % 2 == 0:
            current_loss = closure().item()
            pbar.set_description("Step: %d | Loss: %.6f" %
                                 (step, current_loss))
train()


What do you mean by interrupting? Do you save a ckpt from which you restore the weights?  Do you also restore the optimizer state?

No, I just stop the code and then start it again from that state. I used google colab and can interrupt the cell with training. I thought that when I am interuppt the code the model parameters aer saved in its last state as an optimizer.

That is correct. But how are you continuing the process then? AFAIK, you can only restart but not resume the cell. Have you printed the step and made sure it continues where it left off?

Yes, I am sure because I am not restart the model. I define it in the cell above.

You are right. Then the problem is only that you are redefining the optimizer in the snippet above. Just move this up as well.
